# Planet API Access Key

Tags: api, planet

The Planet says that we need to add API key to the environment. 
I am trying to do it as:

```
export PL_API_KEY=a3a64774d30c4749826b6be445489d3b
```

and getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What I am doing wrong?

---

I am typing it in cmd.exe.

I am trying to do:

```
pip install planet
```

It is not working either

Somehow, I feel that all these errors have the same source, but I can't fix it.

Comment: That's the right way to set an environment variable in a bash or bash-compatible shell. Where have you put this command?

Comment: I am typing it in cmd.exe.

I am trying to do:
pip install planet It is not working either

Somehow, I feel that all these errors have the same source, but I can't fix it.

Comment: "`pip install planet` It is not working either" Please edit your question and include the exact error as text (not a screenshot), otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SyntaxError` means you're typing it in a python prompt, not a command prompt.

`export` is Linux/Unix syntax, for Windows you need to use `set`.

Comment: Hi Luke, Thank you very much. I did set and it worked.